# gettext frequent language switching

Tags: c++, gettext

I am using `gettext` in multiplatform C++ project that acts something like terminal server (very simplified point of view). Its users can change own language at runtime, so at the moment there might be two users with different language set.

As [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#gettext-grok) says it's possible, but I am a little bit unsure about switching speed since this operation will be performed every second (depending on user interaction with the system).

I don't have thread for every user, so changing locale of a single thread is not a solution for me.

So the question is - can `gettext` perform well for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I haven't found better solution than using `boost::spirit` and [spirit_po](https://github.com/cbeck88/spirit-po) library. Then I use spirit_po to load two different catalogs and switching is performed by custom translation macros. However I am not happy about this solution since it introduces dependency to boost.